# Property of independent variable in simple regression.

Tags: statistics, regression

My doubts stem from an article in the web which stated "Simple linear regression is a statistical method that allows us to summarize and study relationships between two continuous (quantitative) variables."

Is simple linear regression a test of relationship between two continuous variables only, or can a categorical variable with two levels be used to form a simple linear regression equation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple linear regression is a model of the following form 
$$
y=\beta_0 + \beta_1x+\epsilon,
$$
where $\epsilon\sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$, $\beta$ are parameters and $x$ is statistically constant, hence $y \sim (\beta_0+\beta_1x, \sigma^2)$. So, the dependent variable $y$ have to be continuous, while $x$ can be discrete or continuous. Where $x$ is categorical variable, this model is called One-Way-ANOVA. In this case, you mostly interest in comparison of means of $y$ between various levels of $x$.